# how can I use .env files with firebase hosting?

Tags: next.js, google-cloud-functions, environment-variables, firebase-hosting

I made .env file in nextjs app, and I use the environment variables on local.
It was worked perfectly. But after I deployed with firebase hosting, error occured.
The error is caused by the environmental variable not being recognized.
how can I use .env file with firebase hosting?
I spent 3 hours on this error..

It's my .env file

```js
NEXT_PUBLIC_MONGO_URI=
NEXT_PUBLIC_MORALIS_API_KEY=
NEXT_PUBLIC_ALCHEMY_API_KEY=
NEXT_PUBLIC_NEXTAUTH_SECRET=
NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_STORAGE_URL=
```

Comment: You can use `dotenv cli` and run the app to take the .env by follwoing command `dotenv .env && your app bootstrap script`!

Comment: or take a look at the similiar  issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/68482475